# macOS/SwiftUI: set selection color/tint of date picker when using GraphicalDatePickerStyle()?

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm implementing a date picker (with native calendar style) for a macOS menu bar utility built with SwiftUI. This is being achieved with the following code:

```swift
DatePicker(model.datePickerLabel,
           selection: $viewModel.selectedDate,
           displayedComponents: .date)
    .labelsHidden()
    .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
```

Nothing wrong with it, and it's also behaving properly, but I would like to set the color/tint for the day selected by the user. The tint/color seems to be only applied to the current day of the calendar, while having a greyish background when a different day is selected (in light mode). This is not right especially given that, while in dark mode, selection is not even marked with any color whatsoever.

Current day selected in dark mode (April 04):

[image: current day in dark mode]

Another day selected in dark mode (April 05):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently was a bug. Seems to have been solved in macOS 10.15.4.